# I can not start my cloned next js project with npm run dev and there is no error message

Tags: next.js, npm-install, git-clone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egM87.png)I cloned a nextjs project repo from my github it is my repo and I am the owner of the project after that I run npm install and every thing was okay and then I tried to start the project using npm run dev it showed me that the app is running on port 3000 and after that it stopped running the app as if I run ctrl+c (the port 3000 is not  in use)

I am trying to start my next js cloned project but it did not work can anyone help please

Comment: Try to kill all your node process and try again